# Cut off variable after X amount characters in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with the following if statement included in it. I want to be able to echo the first 12 characters of the variable PanoramaRaw so that I can turn it into a variable with just the first 12 characters in it. It seems my method doesn't work and I am open to suggestions, thanks.

```
panoramaRaw=$(grep panorama_client.so /proc/$PID/maps)
    if [$panoramaRaw == *"r-xp"*]; then
            echo $panoramaRaw | head -c 12
            fi
```

`

Comment: With bash: `echo ${panoramaRaw:0:12}`

Comment: The output of this is the same. It outputs the string uncut.

Comment: there is a syntax error in your `if [$panoramaRaw == *"r-xp"*]` statement. I don't know if this is a typo in your question or not, but you need a space like so : `[ $panoramaRaw == *"r-xp"* ]`. Also, the operator to compare regex is `=~` in bash

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. It works now.

Comment: @Aserre `*"r-xp"*` is a glob pattern, but `[ ]` doesn't support it either; `[[ ]]` with `=`/`==` does.

Comment: you can also compare your pattern using `=~` operator: `[[ $panoramaRaw =~ "r-xp" ]]`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, it just grabs the first 12 any character on the line.

```
$ s='12345678901112'
$ echo $s | egrep -o '^.{12}'
123456789011
```